# Excel 2007 - How to determine a column is calculated or not

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have the following situation:

I have a work sheet which contains a list of work with the estimated hours.
These hours can be assigned to users (listed in column D and E) using column C.
Now I want calculate the assigned hours per user in columns D E and F.

I am able to fill in the values for the not calculated fields using the following function:
I am using already the following functions (removed the $ sign for readability and I am using record 3 as example because it is not calculated)

- Calculation for assigned hours : `=IF(C3=D1;B3;0)`. So if the name of the user is equal to the name of the assigned user then the value will be used, otherwise 0.
- Calculation for not assigned hours : `=SUM(D3:E3) - B3`. So if the assigned user does not exist in the columns then the hours are not assigned.

  - ***EDIT*** I have edited the calculation for not assigned hours. The previous version was:`=IF(AND(C3<>D1; C3<>E1);B3;0)`

These two calculations works fine but of course not for the calculated fields.

**What I want to accomplish**

Now I want to fill in the calculations on the question marks. This is easy if you know where the calculated fields are placed but that can be everywhere. So I need to have a function which does the following thing:

```
if: The value of columns B is calculated
then: calculate all values for the certain user until the next calculated row 
else: use one of the two calculations I have already described
```

Requested results using the sample sheet:

- `?1?`: `SUM(D3;D6)`
- `?2?`: `SUM(E3;E6)`
- `?3?`: `SUM(F3;F6)`
- `?4?`: `SUM(D8;D9)`
- `?5?`: `SUM(E8;E9)`
- `?6?`: `SUM(F8;F9)`

**Example sheet**

```
       A          B            C           D            E           F
1|   Tasks   |   Hours   |Assigned To|   User1   |   User2   |Not Assigned|
2|Main Task  |=SUM(A3:A6)|           |    ?1?    |    ?2?    |     ?3?    |
3|  Sub Task |    10     |   User1   |    10     |           |            |
4|  Sub Task |    25     |   User2   |           |    25     |            |
5|  Sub Task |    14     |   User2   |           |    14     |            |
6|  Sub Task |    17     |   User1   |    17     |           |            |
7|Main Task  |=SUM(A8:A9)|           |    ?4?    |    ?5?    |     ?6?    |
8|  Sub Task |    22     |   User2   |           |    22     |            |
9|  Sub Task |    43     |           |           |           |     43     |
```

Explanation:
Column `A`: Each sub task has one extra indent (using the [image: indent] button) in comparison with its parent task.

Column `B`: The value in this column will be calculated if the item contains subitems

```
Task 1        Calculated because contains subtasks (Task 1.1 and Task 1.2)
 Task 1.1     Calculated because contains subtasks (Task 1.1.1 and Task 1.1.2)
  Task 1.1.1  Not calculated because no subtasks
  Task 1.1.2  Not calculated because no subtasks
 Task 1.2     Not calculated because no subtasks
Task 2        Not calculated because no subtasks
Task 3        Calculated because contains subtasks (Task 3.1)
 Task 3.1     Not calculated because no subtasks
```

Column `C`: Only not calculated columns can be assigned to a user

Column `D - E`: The header contains the name of the user where tasks can be assigned to

Column `F`: Contains the not assigned hours per task

Comment: Why don't you just fill the `SUM()` formulas in ColA over to the other columns?

Comment: I'm afraid your example doesn't make much sense. For one, your `SUM`s would be circular references. Also, it seems like your table is poorly laid out and even redundant. What is the overall goal of this worksheet? If you're asking what I think you are, then why not insert a table with a Total Row, then select `SUM` from the dropdown box for cols C:E? In fact, you could do that for col A, then just filter col B (user) to see their total hours. Please clarify your objective, though.

Comment: @Zairja Can you explain why the `SUM`s would be circular references?

Comment: @Zairja: The main goal is to pivot all users next to the tasks and show where that particular user needs to spend its hours on. I know it is redundant but it has some value if my problem is solved. I know I can use filters but still you need to have it grouped and calculated per main task. Note also that I am not allowed to change the first 3 columns. So it is provided with Calculated main tasks and multiple subtasks. I have to use that structure.

Comment: @hwcverwe Can you provide a screenshot or provide some more clarification on how Col A is organized. I have some solutions in mind, but they'd have to know how you tell when a new "Main Task" begins. How are they organized - how would you tell the difference between where sub task(s) end and the next main task starts? Also, you can't alter Cols A:C, but will the `SUM` of hours from a task always be calculated (e.g. B2, B7) or is it sometimes blank?

Comment: @Zairja I have calcified Col A in my question at the end. Thanks about that. I have also changed the way to calculated the not assigned hours. The answer on your question about Cols A:C, The `SUM` of the task will always be calculated. So B2 and B7 will never be blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine which cells have formulas like so:

```
Range formulaCells = range.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeFormulas);
```

[Edit for VBA]

You can create a User Defined Function like the one at [Does Cell Have Formula](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ExcelIsFormula.htm) from Excel VBA then use it like:

> =IsFormula(A1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this mean I need to use macros to solve my problem?

Comment: @hwcverwe Apologies, I was thinking that you were already automating this.  It may not be a requirement, however, using VBA would be my first line of attack, after a quick search of the Excel documentation. If you want to go the VBA route I can provide additional examples. **Note:** The code above is from C# Excel interop.

Comment: no problem. Still interested to know for other users of stackoverflow. But yeah can you provide me an VBA example. Thanks in advance